# Trying to run Apache/NIFI on Zookeeper from Confluent

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-nifi, confluent-platform

I am trying to run Apache/NIFI on confluent-zookeeper. NIFI ver 1.11.3 installed in /opt/nifi by unpacking tar container, confluent is community edition, ver 5.3. installed using confluent repo https://packages.confluent.io/rpm/5.3.

So NIFI works using integrated zookeper, NIFI works if I download zookeeper separatly  from Apache/zookeeper site. Confluent Kafka also works with separate zookeeper and NIFI-integrated. BUT I cannot make it works using zookeeper from confluent.

In logs I see only one warning which is:

```
WARN Received packet at server of unknown type 15 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
```

My config file for all three zookeepers are the same:

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper/
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
server.1=myhost1:2888:3888
server.2=myhost2:2888:3888
server.3=myhost3:2888:3888
autopurge.snapRetainCount=3
autopurge.purgeInterval=24
```

I do not think that Confluent really changed smth in their zookeeper. What could be the reason of this error?

Comment: What version of "zookeeper from confluent" are you using if that's a valid question to ask. It might as well be a version compatibility issue.

Comment: Your zookeeper configuration is a bit old, and it is not compatible with info 0.11. Check the zookeeper version.

Comment: NiFi 1.11.x requires ZK 3.5, please confirm the version of ZK used in Confluent platform, if its 3.4 then its not going to work

Comment: 1 ) so, according to this document:
https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html
on 5.3 confluent should be 3.4.14 zookeeper.
2) Downloaded from Apache version is 3.6.0 

Is there difference  between them ?

Answer (score 0):

As @BryanBende said:

> NiFi 1.11.x (In our particular case, 1.11.4) requires ZK 3.5, please
> confirm the version of ZK used in Confluent platform, **IF ITS 3.4 THEN
> ITS NOT GOING TO WORK** – Bryan Bende Mar 27 at 14:35

The typical error you will see in zookeeper log:

> Oct 08 17:22:23 some-pro-zk03 zookeeper-server-start[14136]:
> [2020-10-08 17:22:23,275] INFO Accepted socket connection from
> /10.10.10.1:53794 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)

> Oct 08 17:22:23 some-pro-zk03 zookeeper-server-start[14136]:
> [2020-10-08 17:22:23,275] INFO Refusing session request for client
> /10.10.10.1:53794 as it hasseen zxid 0x400000000 our last zxid is
> 0x300000004 client must try another server
> (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)

> Oct 08 17:22:23
> some-pro-zk03 zookeeper-server-start[14136]: [2020-10-08 17:22:23,275]
> INFO Closed socket connection for client /10.159.164.93:53794 (no
> session established for client)
> (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)

The typical error you will see in client log:

> 2020-10-07 16:00:09,112 ERROR [Curator-Framework-0]
> o.a.c.f.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl Background operation retry gave
> uporg.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException:
> KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLossat
> org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:102)at
> org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.checkBackgroundRetry(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:862)at
> org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.performBackgroundOperation(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:990)at
> org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.backgroundOperationsLoop(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:943)at
> org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.access$300(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:66)at
> org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$4.call(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:346)at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

This takes a full day of work (reading logs!!) to find the error.
So, check your zookeeper version:

FOR **Zookeeper 3.5+**

```
echo srvr | nc localhost 2181
```

FOR **Zookeeper 3.5<**

```
echo stats | nc localost 2181
```

Also you can use telnet

FOR **Zookeeper 3.5+**

```
telnet localhost 2181
srvr
```

FOR **Zookeeper 3.5<**

```
telnet localhost 2181
stats
```